# System.OutOfMemoryException in foreach loop over worsheet rows

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

I am trying to open an excel file and place the contents into a datatable for further use in my program. The program is receiving the error in the subject title.

```
private void ReadExcelToDataSet(string FileName,string Worksheet)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorksheet;

        xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(FileName);
        xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[Worksheet];

        System.Data.DataTable ReadExcel = new System.Data.DataTable();
        Range UsedRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;

        foreach(Range row in xlWorksheet.Rows)
        {
            ReadExcel.Rows.Add(xlWorksheet.Rows.Value);
        }

        dataGridViewTest.DataSource = ReadExcel;
    }
```

The program is failing on the line:

```
ReadExcel.Rows.Add(xlWorksheet.Rows.Value);
```

The worksheet isn't particularly large, and all the data is either strings or numbers (no images or charts).  I'm assuming that there is something fundamentally wrong with trying to add an Excel Row to a datatable row.  What would be the correct method to read Excel to a datatable using Interop, or what should I do to prevent my out of memory problem?  Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Are you sure your `foreach` loop is reading only non-empty rows? Can you put a counter in it and see how large it gets, or debug and see what is the value of `xlWorksheet.Rows.Count`?

Comment: I don't happen to use these interop tools, so forgive my ignorance, but is this normal that you don't use the `foreach` variable `row` in your loop, and adding instead `Rows.Value`?

Comment: Floremin led me to some interesting information.  xlWorksheet.Rows.Count returned a number of rows equal to 65536, which is way more than actually used.  Strangely enough, the out of memory occurs on the first iteration of the foreach loop.  I'm assuming it is probably also trying to put the maximum number of columns into the datatable.  I must be doing something wrong with reading excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var ReadExcel = new System.Data.DataTable();
var UsedRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;
// Add a new column to the DataTable
var column = new DataColumn();
column.ColumnName = "rowValue";
ReadExcel.Columns.Add(column);

foreach (Range row in xlWorksheet.Rows)
{               
    var newrow = ReadExcel.NewRow();
    // Add row.Value NOT xlWorksheet.Rows.Value
    newrow["rowValue"] = row.Value;
    ReadExcel.Rows.Add(newrow);
}
```

Basically, you've had `xlWorksheet.Rows.Value` instead of `row.Value`. But I'm guessing you'll also want to correctly use the `DataTable`. See here for examples: [DataTable.NewRow Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.newrow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) . I've also used [implicit typing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx). It's easier for the eyes.

Comment: This works, it seems.  My line of code that says: dataGridViewTest.DataSource = ReadExcel; only puts the information System.Object[,] into each row, and there is only one column of data.  Is this the expected result?

Comment: I can't see what `dataGridViewTest` is. And it depends on how you looked at it.

Comment: You'll basically have a `DataTable` object stored in `dataGridViewTest.DataSource`. To read the contents, you should use the [Rows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.rows%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

Comment: If there is no reason to use a `DataTable` (I haven't used one before), you could as well use a [List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It's easier to work with. You might have specific needs here, I don't know, but List should be easier.